# OpenID connect authentication

Tags: community, open-id-connect

I am working on a Salesforce community usecase and for automatic user provisioning I am using an Identity provider for my OpendID connect flow.

Everything is working fine, however there is a scenario, where based on certain conditions user is not created and an exception is thrown. This error is properly handled by community exception page, but nobody (Salesforce admin) is informed about this.

So I tried to setup a custom object and capture details about this exception in the catch block and return a Null (No exception thrown) from my Registration Handler. More details here for Registration Handler https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_auth_plugin.htm

It shows as a success in the debug logs, but the whole transaction is reverted back, therefore none of the date is stored in the custom object. I think Salesforce is still considering it as a exception scenario.

So the question is, is there a way that I can inform Salesforce admin about this exception?

Comment: Instead of storing exception details in custom object can you email the exception message to sytem admin?

Comment: That would be fine, if we can do that. But 'm afraid, as SF is considering this as an exception, no emails will be sent.